# Why is my Mango leaves turning brown?

Tags: fruit-trees, leaves

Can someone help me?!?!? I started leaving my mango plant outside so it can get used to it, but 2 days later the leaves started turning brown! It was fine the first day, but when I woke up in the morning on the second day the leaves were brown. I don’t know what to do. Is it normal for the plant to turn brown? If anyone knows please tell me what to do, I want the leaves to turn green again. Btw I am new gardener, that is why I am really worried.

[image]

Comment: It might be a reaction to the new light intensity (outside light is more intense). My advice is to let it get used to outside sunlight, by giving it a little more light every day during morning or evening sun. Build it up slowly.

Answer (score 0):

that is a soil issue. you need to remove it and make a soil that is a 50/50 mix of peat and perlite and also add some sand to the mix. that soil looks very compact and the roots cant breathe which is slowly killing the plant. also it is too young to get full direct sun.

Comment: It definitely looks like it needs more aireation (perlite), but if the plant with the same soil, never had an issue, leaving it outside would only but help (unless it rains or it is very humid) for aireation...

Answer (score 0):

A young mango plant often has green and brown leaves.  So it is hard to say if there is something wrong with it.

There are many photos, [here](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/young-mango-leaves.html?sortBy=relevant) protected, so I can't copy them here.  This is my memory of the plants when I was in India.

There would be reason to worry if they started to shrivel or curl.